# how to wrap the text in UITable cell in Iphone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my iPhone application UITable having So many cells with Text. The Text size is more than the width of the device. How can I wrap the text in cell and display the text in the different lines or divide it in the lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a UILabel as a subview of a cell in a

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method. Then set its lineBreakMode and numberOfLines properties as you want. The code must look something like this:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tID];
  if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:tID] autorelease];
 }
else{
       UIView *tView = [cell viewWithTag:100];
    [tView removeFromSuperview];
}
UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 0, 90, 50)];
label.tag = 100;
label.numberOfLines = 2;
label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
label.text = @"Putyourverylongcelltexthere";
[cell addSubview:label];
[label release];
```